# \cite* year with origdate in square brackets

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I am using the package `biblatex-chicago` with option `authordate` for citations.

Some of the authors and works that I cite are part of the structure of sentences, so I cannot use straightforward commands like `\textcite` and the like.

However, I still want the year to be displayed in round brackets and hyperlinked to the bibliography. My solution would be to cite the author or work with either `\citeauthor` or `\citetitle` in the appropriate place within the sentence, and then put a `\cite*` command inside round brackets to get the desired effect.

This usually works fine, but things get complicated when bibliographic entries have an additional `origdate` field, as this is printed in round brackets too instead of square brackets.

In short, what I'd need is a hypothetical “`parenciteyear`” command that takes round brackets into account and behaves accordingly.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) of what you have and give precise examples of what the output should be.

Comment: Can't you use `\parencite*` (not tested for lack of MWE and laziness on my part)?

Comment: @moewe so dumb of me. That was so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` also has a starred version of `\parencite`. Use

```
\parencite*
```

to get a parenthetic citation without author name.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,labeldateparts]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kullback:reprint,
  author        = {Kullback, Solomon},
  title         = {Information Theory and Statistics},
  year          = 1997,
  publisher     = {Dover Publications},
  location      = {New York},
  origdate      = 1959,
  origpublisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{kullback:reprint} but \parencite*{kullback:reprint}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]